# Custom GA data costs = Analytics API column missing?

Tags: import, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use custom cost data (from PLA, price comparison sites), I already upload data on daily basis, it shows up in GA. However, It does not work as expected on API side - as I need to use this cost data for custom reporting, using ga:adCost return cost data only for Google Ads, nothing else. As I have checked, there is no other *cost* column in dimensions or metrics....
Concrete:

1. I import cost data using APIs
   [image]
2. Success

[image]
[image]

3. However, on the API side, when I want to use that data as a source for data export, the only ,,cost,, related colum is adCost - but only Google Ads costs as a traffic source are returned

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/
[image]

I would expect all traffic sources to have ga:adCost (or ga:cost?) in API as well, however, only Google Ads have that. I suppose that ga:ad* is related to GAds connection data only and custom data imported are to passed to Analytics API and/or there is no metric for that data...

Am i doing wrong API calls to get traffic source / medium & cost data, or custom imported data are not able to get back via API?

Is there a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and show us in GA where it shows up.

Comment: Updated, hope that describe it better.